# Case sensitivity in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, case, case-sensitive

I have a script that swaps out accented characters for their HTML equivalents, which works well but DOESN'T take into account the case sensitivity of the letters. This causes a lot of issues. I thought maybe the accented characters weren't being recognised as a case in the first place but after some testing I've discovered that that's not the issue since the same problem occurs with regular unaccented letters. I've tried adding considering case but that won't make it work. Here's a sample:

```
   tell application "TextWrangler"

    copy the contents of the selection of window 1 to meinText

    set the contents of the selection of window 1 to asci2html(meinText) of me

end tell

on asci2html(derText)
    considering case
        tell application "TextWrangler"
            set derText to replace "Á" using "&Aacute;" searchingString derText
            set derText to replace "á" using "&aacute;" searchingString derText
            set derText to replace "A" using "BIG" searchingString derText
            set derText to replace "a" using "little" searchingString derText
            return derText
        end tell
    end considering
end asci2html
```

That will test for an accented char as well as just the letter 'A' and if you run it on the following chars you'll see it doesn't differentiate case:

a
A
Á
á

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: `considering / ignoring` affects only string comparisons. In this case it has no effect.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's helpful. I tried another version of this that did a string comparison as well (defining a lowercase alphabet and then checking to see if my chars were in it before choosing the replacement) but my derText variable contains the ENTIRE string (which of course wouldn't appear in my alphabet) and not each individual character I'm scrubbing. It seems like I need to have this script run each character it encounters through the comparison/replacement individually. Any quick pointers on how to do that? Thanks

Comment: This is basically what I mocked up but like I said, derText isn't an individual character, it's the entire selection I'm scrubbing. How can I have it run this for each character it encounters?: 
 considering case
   
   set lowercase to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   if lowercase contains derText then
    set derText to replace "a" using "little" searchingString derText
   else
    set derText to replace "A" using "BIG" searchingString derText
   end if
  end considering

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it, using some code I adapted from macosxautomation.com:

```
tell application "TextWrangler"
    set outputText to "nuthing"
    copy the contents of the selection of window 1 to meinText
    set the contents of the selection of window 1 to asci2html(meinText) of me
    return outputText
end tell


on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    considering case
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
        set the item_list to every text item of this_text
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
        set this_text to the item_list as string
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        return this_text
    end considering
end replace_chars

on asci2html(derText)

    set the derText to replace_chars(derText, "a", "little")
    set the derText to replace_chars(derText, "A", "BIG")
    set outputText to derText

end asci2html
```

I'm sure it's not entirely efficient: I'm bouncing the values between a couple of different variables to side-step some errors that I couldn't figoure out, but it seems to be working anyway, as seen by the before-after screenshot! Any thoughts?

[Screenshot-before-after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMEhL.jpg)

Comment:  Thanks!

  Wrapping my whole if-then-else clause with its case sensitive string comparison into a `considering case` block did the job!

ℹ️ Final code: `considering case LINEBREAK lines which make up the if-then-else clause LINEBREAK end considering`.